# Android 8.1.0 Native Crash：#00 pc 0001a772 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+63) [armeabi-v8]

Tags: android

I'm seeing this native crash in Bugly with the following stack trace.
The crash happens in 4,108 times which in Android 8.1.0 only. 
More and more Android devices update OS; that make the crash to seem seriously.

Any advice will be appreciated!

```
#00 pc 0001a4f8 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+63) [armeabi-v8]
#01 pc 0001a4f4 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+59) [armeabi-v8]
#02 pc 0001a4f0 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+55) [armeabi-v8]
#03 pc 0001a4ec /system/lib/libc.so (abort+51) [armeabi-v8]
#04 pc 0001a4e8 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+47) [armeabi-v8]
#05 pc 0001a4e4 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+43) [armeabi-v8]
#06 pc 0001a4e0 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+39) [armeabi-v8]
#07 pc 0001a4dc /system/lib/libc.so (abort+35) [armeabi-v8]
#08 pc 0001a4d8 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+31) [armeabi-v8]
#09 pc 0001a4d4 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+27) [armeabi-v8]
#10 pc 0001a4d0 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+23) [armeabi-v8]
#11 pc 0001a4cc /system/lib/libc.so (abort+19) [armeabi-v8]
#12 pc 0001a4c8 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+15) [armeabi-v8]
#13 pc 0001a4c4 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+11) [armeabi-v8]
#14 pc 0001a4c0 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+7) [armeabi-v8]
#15 pc 0001a4bc /system/lib/libc.so (abort+3) [armeabi-v8]
#16 pc 0001a4b8 /system/lib/libc.so (__set_errno_internal+15)    [armeabi-v8]
#17 pc 0001a4b4 /system/lib/libc.so (__set_errno_internal+11) [armeabi-v8]
#18 pc 0001a4b0 /system/lib/libc.so (__set_errno_internal+7) [armeabi-v8]
#19 pc 0001a4ac /system/lib/libc.so (__set_errno_internal+3) [armeabi-v8]
#20 pc 0001a4a8 /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_current_sigrtmin+3) [armeabi-v8]
#21 pc 0001a4a4 /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_current_sigrtmax+3) [armeabi-v8]
#22 pc 0001a4a0 /system/lib/libc.so (__gnu_basename+21) [armeabi-v8]
#23 pc 0001a49c /system/lib/libc.so (__gnu_basename+17) [armeabi-v8]
#24 pc 0001a498 /system/lib/libc.so (__gnu_basename+13) [armeabi-v8]
#25 pc 0001a494 /system/lib/libc.so (__gnu_basename+9) [armeabi-v8]
#26 pc 0001a490 /system/lib/libc.so (__gnu_basename+5) [armeabi-v8]
#27 pc 0001a48c /system/lib/libc.so (__gnu_basename+1) [armeabi-v8]
#28 pc 0001a488 /system/lib/libc.so (__errno+5) [armeabi-v8]
#29 pc 0001a484 /system/lib/libc.so (__errno+1) [armeabi-v8]
#30 pc 0001a480 /system/lib/libc.so (__cmsg_nxthdr+27) [armeabi-v8]
#31 pc 0001a47c /system/lib/libc.so (__cmsg_nxthdr+23) [armeabi-v8]
#32 pc 0001a478 /system/lib/libc.so (__cmsg_nxthdr+19) [armeabi-v8]
#33 pc 0001a474 /system/lib/libc.so (__cmsg_nxthdr+15) [armeabi-v8]
#34 pc 0001a470 /system/lib/libc.so (__cmsg_nxthdr+11) [armeabi-v8]
#35 pc 0001a46c /system/lib/libc.so (__cmsg_nxthdr+7) [armeabi-v8]
#36 pc 0001a468 /system/lib/libc.so (__cmsg_nxthdr+3) [armeabi-v8]
#37 pc 0001a464 /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_get_shell_path+147) [armeabi-v8]
#38 pc 0001a460 /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_get_shell_path+143) [armeabi-v8]
#39 pc 0001a45c /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_get_shell_path+139) [armeabi-v8]
#40 pc 0001a458 /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_get_shell_path+135) [armeabi-v8]
#41 pc 0001a454 /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_get_shell_path+131) [armeabi-v8]
#42 pc 0001a450 /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_get_shell_path+127) [armeabi-v8]
#43 pc 0001a44c /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_get_shell_path+123) [armeabi-v8]
#44 pc 0001a448 /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_get_shell_path+119) [armeabi-v8]
#45 pc 0001a444 /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_get_shell_path+115) [armeabi-v8]
#46 pc 0001a440 /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_get_shell_path+111) [armeabi-v8]
#46 pc 0001a72c /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_get_shell_path+107) [armeabi-v7a]
#47 pc 0001a728 /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_get_shell_path+103) [armeabi-v7a]
#48 pc 0001a724 /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_get_shell_path+99) [armeabi-v7a]
#49 pc 0001a720 /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_get_shell_path+95) [armeabi-v7a]
#50 pc 0001a71c /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_get_shell_path+91) [armeabi-v7a]
```

Comment: Can you post the code that is causing this to happen?

Comment: @SeanPianka Sorry，this log is copied from Bugly website which used to gather crashs and display.So i don't konw which code cause this crash.